# Excel: Get text between two characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the text between the last `/` and `'` in the column below:

[image]

So that my answer will be:

[image]

I tried using the formulas:

```
=MID(A5, SEARCH("/", A5)+1, SEARCH("''", A5) - SEARCH("/", A5) -1)
```

and

```
=MID(RIGHT(A5,FIND("/",A5)-1),FIND("/",A5)+1,LEN(A5))
```

But unfortunately they aren't working.

Comment: I'm trying to get the text between **the last** `/` and **the last** `'`.

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A2,"/"),-1),"'","")`

Comment: Hi @Scott unfortunately that formula isn't working

Comment: @tadm123 what error are you getting?

Comment: sorry missed a `,`: `=SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A2,"/"),,-1),"'","")`

Comment: Thanks it works now, but is there a way to not show the cells in which its text aren't between these two characters? For example the first row `34 Composition-Software....` would be left out of the final answer

Comment: @tadm123 check my answer `TEXTAFTER` is suitable for this kind of scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"/",-1),"'","")
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

Similarly to get the text before:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A4,"/",-1),"'","")
```

Comment: Or even `=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"/",-1),"'")` would work I suppose.

Comment: Is there a way to filter out cells in which its text aren't between these two characters? For example the first row `34 Composition-Software....` would be filter out of the final answer

Comment: @tadm123 I added also this to my answer